# Best backend server for storing photos on IOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have been working on this app for a quite a while, but I have been experimenting with the Parse back end server to store photos and other text inputs. I feel as as the app grows, it will quickly run out of storage and requests per second on the server will continue to grow. Users upload photos and text strings to the Parse server. Any feedback on Parse reliability or should I look into another back end service to store photos?

Comment: I don't understand the problem... What make you think Parse wouldn't be reliable?

Comment: @LyndseyScott The problem is that i fear it will run out of storage in a short period of time which will lead to problems down the road

Comment: Parse won't run out of storage.

Comment: I predict that each user could have sever hundred photos over time; with that many photos per user and with a growing user base, I feel like the data will add up quick. Parse doc says they allow up to 20 gb and you can add additional storage for a fee but it doesn't seem like much storage space overall

Answer (score 1):

My experience with parse has been great. Easy to use SDK, security, platform independence are key factors of continue to using it.
Here are few alternatives

- [Cloudmine](https://cloudmine.me/)
- [Deployd](http://deployd.com/)

Heres a link for more information ["Alternatives to parse"](http://www.developereconomics.com/backend-as-a-service-shootout-the-best-alternatives-to-parse/)